# Label cell goes away with SelectionEvaluate

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, options, cells

When a given cell has a label (given with the CellLabel->"label" option of the cell), then this label disappears after calling

```
SelectionEvaluate[ nb ]
```

when the contents of the cell is selected. Why is that? Is it possible to keep the label after evaluating its content (without making a new cell, so not using the

```
SelectionEvaluateCreateCell[]
```

command?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Could you describe steps you are performing? I can't reproduce your observation. I have to go now but just in case, take a look at `CellLabelAutoDelete`.

Comment: Yes, I can add the steps, of course. Should I add an answer for that, to be able to format it? Thanks!

Comment: CellLabelAutoDelete seems to do the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try:

```
Options[EvaluationCell[], CellLabelAutoDelete]
```

> ```
> {CellLabelAutoDelete -> True}
> ```

so you see we have to change this default setting by

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellLabelAutoDelete -> False]
```

(*`EvaluationCell[]` is only for example, do this for the cells you need to*)

For global control go to `Options Inspector`:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> **> Cell Options > Cell Labels > CellLabelAutoDelete**